# Preventing keyboard to reopen in Android

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a large EditText field in Android. If the user clicks the first time on it, it gets the focus and the keyboard opens.

But if I click on the EditText again, the Keyboard closes and directly opens again. Do you have any idea to keep to keyboard open?

Comment: Please share code too

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to keep the keyboard open when clicking on an EditText field in Android:

Method 1: Using

```
editText.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
```

This will prevent the keyboard from automatically opening when the EditText field gets focus. You can then manually open the keyboard using the InputMethodManager class.

```
val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(editText, 0);
```

Method 2: Using a custom EditText view
You can create a custom EditText view that overrides the onFocusChanged() method. In the onFocusChanged() method, you can check if the keyboard is already open. If it is not, you can open it manually.

Here is an example of a custom EditText view that keeps the keyboard open:

```
class MyEditText(context: Context) : EditText(context) {

override fun onFocusChanged(focused: Boolean, direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect?) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect)

    if (focused && !isKeyboardOpen()) {
        showKeyboard()
    }
}

private fun isKeyboardOpen(): Boolean {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    return inputMethodManager.isActive && inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText
}

private fun showKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(this, 0)
}
}
```

To use the custom EditText view, simply replace the EditText view in your layout with your custom EditText view.

```
<com.example.myapp.MyEditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Which method you choose depends on your specific needs. If you only need to keep the keyboard open for a single EditText field, then you can use the TextView.setShowSoftInputOnFocus() method. If you need to keep the keyboard open for multiple EditText fields, or if you need more control over the keyboard, then you can use a custom EditText view.